# How to create a projectile motion of a cannonball in top down view?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, projectile-physics

**Objective**

- To move the bullet with projectile motion to specific destination by touch point.

In the below image is an example of a bullet which has a projectile motion. On my observation, the bullet speed and angle is calculated base on distance.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pixwerk.net](http://pixwerk.net/home/images/gifs/slimeWeapon.gif))</sub>

**Where I'm at?** *(How do I move the bullet to its destination?)*

In the below code, is the method I use *to move a bullet to its destination*. But the problem is I want to create a cannonball bullet which it has a projectile motion. How do I create these tricks to make a cannon ball projectile motion like the image below.

```
public Vector2 getVelocity(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 targetPosition) {
    Vector2 targetDirection = targetPosition.cpy().sub(currentPosition);
    return targetDirection
            .nor();
}
```

**What I have done?** *(Currently I could move the bullet straight to its destination.)*

- Bullet is moving straight *(It's not problem)*.

[image]

**[EDIT]**

**Drawing a projected trajectory**

To get the trajectory point, base on [iforced example](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/projected-trajectory). I've already have the libgdx box2d version of this.

```
b2Vec2 getTrajectoryPoint( b2Vec2& startingPosition, b2Vec2& startingVelocity, float n )
  {
      //velocity and gravity are given per second but we want time step values here
      float t = 1 / 60.0f; // seconds per time step (at 60fps)
      b2Vec2 stepVelocity = t * startingVelocity; // m/s
      b2Vec2 stepGravity = t * t * m_world->GetGravity(); // m/s/s

      return startingPosition + n * stepVelocity + 0.5f * (n*n+n) * stepGravity;
  }
```

Rendering the trajectory point

```
glColor3f(1,1,0);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) { // three seconds at 60fps
      b2Vec2 trajectoryPosition = getTrajectoryPoint( startingPosition, startingVelocity, i );
      glVertex2f(trajectoryPosition.x, trajectoryPosition.y );
  }
  glEnd();
```

**[Solve]**

The answer is to find the angle and speed by the distance by [s.tarik.cetin](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/74040/s-tar%C4%B1k-%C3%87etin)

**Another issue encountered** *(this must be move to another question)*

This is the problem, I don't know how do I set the starting velocity. Currently in the below code, to set the `startingVelocity` and `startingPosition` where the underlined code is the part that I'm not sure.

```
    touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(touchPoint);

    Vector2 touch = new Vector2(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
    Vector2 touchDirection = touch.cpy().sub(bulletPosition).nor(); // get the the direction from bullet position to touch point and normalize the value.

    float distance = touchDirection.dst(startingPosition);
    float angle = touch.angle();
    float speed = 6.0f; // currently the speed is fixed. I need to know the speed base on distance

    startingPosition.set(bulletPosition); // current position of the bullet
    startingVelocity.set(touchDirection.scl(speed)); // where the bullet should be
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion):

$$d=\frac{v_0^2}{g}sin(2\theta)$$

When you reverse the formula to find the angle from the distance and initial speed, it becomes:

$$\eqalign{
d&=\frac{v_0^2}{g}sin(2\theta) \\
sin(2\theta)&=\frac{dg}{v_0^2} \\
arcsin(sin(2\theta))&=arcsin(\frac{dg}{v_0^2}) \\
2\theta&=arcsin(\frac{dg}{v_0^2}) \\
\theta&=(arcsin(\frac{dg}{v_0^2}))/2 \\
}$$

So you can define this method:

```
double gravity; //Assuming you preset this.

double GetLaunchAngle (double distance, double initialSpeed)
{
    double sineValue = distance * gravity / Math.Pow(initialSpeed, 2);

    if(sineValue < -1 || sineValue > 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("There is no possible way of reaching the given distance with given initial speed.");
    }

    return Math.Asin(sineValue) /2;
}
```

Now, you can use the launch angle to launch your projectile, so it would draw a parabola in the air, just like the image you posted.

For the explanation of why we have an exception in method, check [this section of the wikipedia article about projectile movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Maximum_distance_of_projectile).

---

**Edit:**
If the intial velocity is not an essential part of your game, we can eliminate the exception by letting the game decide a suitable speed by fixing the launch angle:

```
double gravity; //Assuming you preset this.
double fixedLaunchAngle = 45; //This can be any angle, but you get the most distance with least speed if your launch angle is 45 degrees.

double GetInitialSpeed (double distance)
{
    double sine = Math.Sin(2 * fixedLaunchAngle); //You can cache or even hardcode this value to avoid calculating over and over again.
    double squaredSpeed = distance * gravity / sine;
    return Math.Sqrt(squaredSpeed);
}
```

And here is a more generic version that allows you to also specify the launch angle:

```
double gravity; //Assuming you preset this.

double GetInitialSpeed (double distance, double launchAngle)
{
    double sine = Math.Sin(2 * launchAngle); //You can *not* cache this, since it is a parameter now.
    double squaredSpeed = distance * gravity / sine;
    return Math.Sqrt(squaredSpeed);
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning, but the method above returns NaN

Comment: @ronscript For which inputs?

Comment: `getLaunchAngle(-9.8f, 100, 6)`

Comment: @ronscript That's because there is no way of reaching that distance with that initial velocty. Check out the edit.

Comment: should be the distance in meters?

Comment: @ronscript For real life, yes. For your game, the only thing matters is consistent scaling across variables; which means use whatever unit you want, but use the same unit for all variables.

Comment: can you create a graphical usage of this functions? because I'm having hard time understand how it works.

Comment: @ronscript The wikipedia page I linked includes extended graphs and explanations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43278/discussion-between-ronscript-and-s-tarik-cetin).