# How to make the bullet stop accurately when destination is reached?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

In the below code, is the method I use to move a bullet to its destination and stop when bullet is near to destination. But the problem is the bullet is stopping not accurately, sometimes there's a small offset or span or sometimes is accurate depends on the angle.

```
public Vector2 getVelocity(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 targetPosition) {
    Vector2 targetDirection = targetPosition.cpy().sub(currentPosition);
    return targetDirection
            .nor();
}

final float SPEED = 6;
float pos = bulletPosition.len();
float des = bullet.destination.len();
float tol = Constants.TIME_STEP * SPEED;

if(MathUtils.isEqual(pos,des, tol)) {
    body.setLinearVelocity(0,0); 
} else {
    body.setLinearVelocity(getVelocity(bulletPosition, destination).scl(SPEED));
}
```

**[SOLVED]**

```
if(MathUtils.isEqual(pos, des, tol)) {
     // quick & dirty way
     body.setTransform(destination, angle);
     // better way
     ...
}
```

Comment: What does `MathUtils.isEqual` do exactly, is it a direct comparision or an approximation?

Comment: here is the link for `MathUtils` java doc [link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick & Dirty Way:**
You can simply teleport the bullet to location you want after it stops.

**Long & Better Way:**
For the last moments of movement, you can disable the physics and control the movement yourself by lerp'ing *(or any other way, lerp is my favorite)* towards the target. This way, you can stop the bullet whenever you want.

---

**Edit**
I would solve the situation like this in Unity, and actually this might be a better way than the two above:

```
float minDisableDistance, minStopDistance, bulletSpeed;
Transform target;

// I'm skipping the parts that you create the bullet, and simply do the job on these:
GameObject bullet; //Assuming this is the bullet.
Rigidbody bulletRigidbody; //Assuming this is the rigidbody of bullet.

void Update()
{
    Vector3 relPos = target.position - bullet.postion;
    float distance = relPos.magnitude;

    if(distance > minDisableDistance)
    {
        //use physics.
    }
    else
    {
        bulletRigidbody.velocity = 0;

        if(distance > minStopDistance)
        {
            bullet.position += bulletSpeed * relPos.normalized * time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            bullet.position = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ***** it works perfectly! I just tried the _"quick & dirty way"_ . I want to try the better way

Comment: can you give me a little pseudo-code on how do I properly do the properway?

Comment: @ronscript I can't, I have never used libgdx or box2d. The wikipedia article about lerp is great, take a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: On the lerp method third parameter t. Because my bullet is speed is 6. the t is also 6?

Comment: @ronscript No, the third parameter indicates the "ratio" of movement from beginning to end (and third parameter should be in between 0-1 in general). For example if it is 0.5, it means the result is exactly the middle of start and end points.

Comment: I can't understand how do I make the lerp speed at 6 m/s

Comment: Hey! I found a much better way look at my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ronscript Exactly, glad you solved it.

Comment: maybe you could help me to my other related issue, here is the [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126397/how-to-create-a-projectile-motion-of-a-cannonball-in-top-down-view)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the best way! I just use the Vector2 dst method to get the distance between the destination. And hooray!! it was accurate!

```
float distance = bulletPosition.cpy().dst(destination);

float tol = (Constants.TIME_STEP * SPEED) / 2;

if(distance <= tol) {

     body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);

}
```