# How to simulate projectile path in 3D with Physijs andThree.js?

Tags: physics, three.js

I'm new in 3D rendering with WebGL. I would like to simulate a 3D projectile path using Three.js and Physijs.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a projectile motion of a cannonball in top down view?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126397/how-to-create-a-projectile-motion-of-a-cannonball-in-top-down-view)

Comment: What have you tried? As you seem to have found, this is completely possible using the libraries you mentioned—what exactly is the problem with just doing it? Do the library's tutorials not cover simple stuff like dropping or throwing objects?